# How can I write a JUnit test on a button that makes a modal JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, junit

I am currently working on a java swing application that get several inputs from the user. At one point I have a `JButton` who's action listener spawns a modal `JDialog` frame where the user will input data. The button then takes the data and does a bunch of stuff with it. The issue is that I need to test the `JButton` to make sure it functions properly but a unit test will stop as soon as it spawns the new Frame since it is modal. How can I test that the button does in fact spawn a new window, and that the rest of the buttons functions work?

**Note:**

- I cant `frame.setModal(false);` because it is contained in the actionlistner.
- I cant add a check to change if it is modal depending on where the call came from because it would defeat the point of writing a test
- I cant simply make the frame permanently not modal because I want to make sure the user does not interact with the other frames while the dialog is open.

**Example code:**

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        InputDialog inputDialog = new InputDialog(button);
        String value = inputDialog.open();

        // I then do a bunch of stuff with value
    }
```

-

```
    public class InputDialog extends JDialog {

        private JTextField field;

        public String getInput() {
            this.setVisible(true);
            String result = field.getText();
            return result;
        }

        public InputDialog(Component c){
            // set the window settings
            this.setUndecorated(true); // Remove title bar
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setModal(true); // stops interactions with other windows
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(c);
            this.setSize(200, 125);

            // make panel
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 125);
            panel.setLayout(null);
            panel.setBackground(new Color(197, 211, 234));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));

            // set up field
            field = new JTextField();
            field.setBounds(25, 25, 150, 25);
            panel.add(field);

            // set up enter button
            JButton button = new JButton("Submit Value");
            button.setBounds(25, 75, 150, 25);
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    me.dispose();
                }
            });
            panel.add(button);

            this.add(panel);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You should test `ActionListener`, not the button.

Comment: **Update: Solved** It is super janky but what I did is get the absolute X and Y of the button and then use `Robot.mousePress()` + `Robot.mouseRelease()`to click it without making a reference. Then you can find the opened window with `Window.getWindows()` and cast it to the proper type. This gives you a working reference to the spawned object! :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want your unit test to open any UI frames/dialogs at all. Try to use mocking libraries like PowerMock and mock `InputDialog` constructor to return mock `InputDialog` and add expectation that `InputDialog.opne()` method is called when your `JButton` is programatically clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is important to test **all** aspects of your product. But your approach is already flawed.

First of all: you should be really careful what code you put into your ActionListeners. Meaning: these methods are invoked on the [event dispatcher thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). And when you do "too much" on that thread you slow down or even freeze your complete UI.

Then: you have to **fully** segregate UI code from your business logic. Anything that is about computing values should go into distinct classes - which you then test in **isolation**.

In other words: your ActionListener doesn't "do things with `value`" - if at all, the listener knows how to use some other class to "do those things".

Comment: Thank you for the help! Would putting the code that I had in the ActionListener  into a different method and then calling that from the ActionListner be better, or would that still run on the event dispatcher thread? If not how can I separate that code and still have it run as normal?